# What is the collective noun for "Artificial Intelligence"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, collective-nouns

AI is everywhere now, changing our lives for the better or the worse.

But, is there someone here who can tell me what the collective noun for Artificial Intelligence is?

Or do we have to wait for an AI to come up with one...?

Example:

> The ______________ (*colony*?) of AI's collaborated to take over the world.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use this word? Just like a class of students is different from a platoon of soldiers or a demographic of voters, a network of AIs might be different from a line of AIs.

Comment: Can't "AI" itself serve this function? Compare: "The crowd (in the stadium) went wild" and "The AI (in the lab) went berserk."

Comment: @jejorda2 e.g. The colony of AI's collaborated to take over the world

Comment: *SkyNet*, perhaps? ... I'll get me coat.

Comment: Perhaps, a _cloud_?

Comment: So far as I know, we don't even have a "collective noun" for *Human* Intelligence, which has been around for longer than the English language. And we barely even have anything like Artificial Intelligence yet, so it's not clear what range of implementations might eventually exist, let alone how we might refer to them all collectively.

Comment: "intelligence," singular, is a collective (i.e., non-countable) noun--it matters not whether it is artificial or natural. The plural form of this word is "intelligences," as in the sentence "Howard Gardner of Harvard has identified seven distinct intelligences."

Comment: @FumbleFingers - In Star Trek it ***is*** *The Collective*

Comment: Just "Artificial Intelligences"

Comment: This is new, so I think we get to pick. A gaggle of AIs? A horde? Gang? More options ... http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/blogs/99-strange-collective-animal-names

Comment: @FumbleFingers we still need to be prepared for the singularity though. How may we prevail if we don't have a collective noun for it?

Answer (score 2):

Most collective nouns imply a degree of commonality between the individuals forming it.

A *herd* of cows feed together, return to the farm for milking together and even , occasionally, act together to protect each other from a perceived threat.

A *crowd* of people, even if they have not come together for a specific purpose, are aware of each other and their actions can be influenced by other members. The awareness of a flash mob by members of the crowd in a shopping centre will spread as people notice that their neighbours are looking at something they have not yet spotted themselves.

A collection of AIs will have some degree of commonality in this sense and at least some of their communication will use formal networking, probably the internet in most cases. An appropriate collective noun, therefore, might be ***cloud***. This would give sentences like "A cloud of AIs will monitor the  High Street watching for muggers and pickpockets."

A good thing about using *cloud* in this way would be that the AIs could be of different types. In the High Street example there could be drone-implemented AIs flying around, mounted camera AIs capturing higher-quality images and at least one server-based AI coordinating the activity, receiving information received by the others and matching faces with a database, possibly hosted on a remote, AI controlled server. All these AIs, however would be part of the same cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a ***swarm***! I remember hearing this word used in such contexts in sci-fi movies (names of which I can't recall).

> The ***swarm*** of AIs collaborated to take over the world.

ODO:

> **[swarm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/swarm)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1.2** (*a swarm/swarms of*) A large number of people or things
>
> ‘Researchers say a swarm of bouncing, spherical bots the size of
>   baseballs could hop across the red planet to search for life.’
>
> ‘A British aerospace company is now working on a top secret flight
>   system which could allow a pilot to control swarms of unmanned planes
>   from the air.’

Wikipedia:

> *[**Swarm** intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence)* (SI) is the collective behavior of decentralized, self-organized systems, natural or artificial. The
>   concept is employed in work on artificial intelligence.

Comment: Swarm is sometimes used in this context to refer to groups of drones in military discussions although a swarm can also refer to large numbers of armed boats in naval strategy (although it is not generally used in reference to land warfare or to a group of low powered manned aircraft).

Answer (score 1):

### Army

While **army** obviously connotes a more sinister or violent motive, *army* can be used simply to mean a large (organised) group of something.

As used by [Microsoft at an event in March 2016](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/mspoweruser.com/microsoft-reveal-army-artificial-intelligence-bots-build-2016/amp/), it does not have to be related to war.

> #### Microsoft to reveal “an army” of artificial intelligence bots at Build 2016
>
> The software giant will reveal several bots, which will have different tasks. Apparently, some of these bots will allow users to discuss and chat about different things [...] tap into Skype, and help users to schedule deliveries, book hotels, or perform similar tasks. Moreover, the company is also working on an AI bot which will use your smartphone’s camera to see and sense what is around a visually impaired user — for example, it will be able to describe facial expressions, and things like that.

(From article)

Comment: I don't see the term army used in your quote. But I see it in the article. Maybe modify the quote? In any case +1 for an actual real world example.

Comment: @Marc Good point; edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **Singularity**, which is commonly used in pop culture to refer to a future where AI begets even more AI, creating a snowball effect.

You could say, "The Singularity collaborated to take over the world"